# Como não apresentar os levels sem valores utilizando scale_fill_manual?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Este é o data.frame para reprodução do comportamento:

```
structure(list(CAATINGA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("3", 
"4", "15", "21", "25"), class = "factor"), x = c(-37.9473978000952, 
-37.94712830551, -37.9468588109248, -37.9465893163395, -37.9463198217543, 
-37.9468588109248, -37.9465893163395, -37.9463198217543, -37.946050327169, 
-37.94712830551, -37.9468588109248, -37.9465893163395, -37.9463198217543, 
-37.946050327169, -37.9473978000952, -37.94712830551, -37.9468588109248, 
-37.9465893163395, -37.9463198217543, -37.946050327169, -37.9457808325838, 
-37.9473978000952, -37.94712830551, -37.9468588109248, -37.9465893163395, 
-37.9463198217543, -37.946050327169, -37.9457808325838, -37.9476672946805, 
-37.9473978000952, -37.94712830551, -37.9468588109248, -37.9465893163395, 
-37.9463198217543, -37.9476672946805, -37.9473978000952, -37.94712830551, 
-37.9468588109248, -37.9465893163395, -37.9530571863852, -37.9527876918, 
-37.9476672946805, -37.9473978000952, -37.94712830551, -37.9535961755557, 
-37.9533266809705, -37.9530571863852, -37.9527876918, -37.9476672946805, 
-37.9473978000952, -37.953865670141, -37.9535961755557, -37.9533266809705, 
-37.9530571863852, -37.9527876918, -37.9525181972148, -37.953865670141, 
-37.9535961755557, -37.9533266809705, -37.9530571863852, -37.9527876918, 
-37.9541351647262, -37.953865670141, -37.9535961755557, -37.9533266809705, 
-37.9468588109248, -37.9465893163395, -37.9473978000952, -37.94712830551, 
-37.9468588109248, -37.9465893163395, -37.9463198217543, -37.9476672946805, 
-37.9473978000952, -37.94712830551, -37.9468588109248, -37.9465893163395, 
-37.9463198217543, -37.946050327169, -37.948206283851, -37.9479367892657, 
-37.94712830551, -37.9468588109248, -37.9465893163395, -37.9463198217543, 
-37.946050327169, -37.9457808325838, -37.9484757784362, -37.948206283851, 
-37.9476672946805, -37.9473978000952, -37.94712830551, -37.9468588109248, 
-37.9465893163395, -37.9463198217543, -37.946050327169, -37.9457808325838, 
-37.9487452730214, -37.9476672946805, -37.9473978000952), y = c(-7.72169360304366, 
-7.72196309762891, -7.72196309762891, -7.72196309762891, -7.72196309762891, 
-7.72223259221415, -7.72223259221415, -7.72223259221415, -7.72223259221415, 
-7.72250208679939, -7.72250208679939, -7.72250208679939, -7.72250208679939, 
-7.72250208679939, -7.72277158138464, -7.72277158138464, -7.72277158138464, 
-7.72277158138464, -7.72277158138464, -7.72277158138464, -7.72277158138464, 
-7.72304107596988, -7.72304107596988, -7.72304107596988, -7.72304107596988, 
-7.72304107596988, -7.72304107596988, -7.72304107596988, -7.72331057055512, 
-7.72331057055512, -7.72331057055512, -7.72331057055512, -7.72331057055512, 
-7.72331057055512, -7.72358006514037, -7.72358006514037, -7.72358006514037, 
-7.72358006514037, -7.72358006514037, -7.72384955972561, -7.72384955972561, 
-7.72384955972561, -7.72384955972561, -7.72384955972561, -7.72411905431085, 
-7.72411905431085, -7.72411905431085, -7.72411905431085, -7.72411905431085, 
-7.72411905431085, -7.72438854889609, -7.72438854889609, -7.72438854889609, 
-7.72438854889609, -7.72438854889609, -7.72438854889609, -7.72465804348134, 
-7.72465804348134, -7.72465804348134, -7.72465804348134, -7.72465804348134, 
-7.72492753806658, -7.72492753806658, -7.72492753806658, -7.72492753806658, 
-7.72573602182231, -7.72573602182231, -7.72600551640755, -7.72600551640755, 
-7.72600551640755, -7.72600551640755, -7.72600551640755, -7.7262750109928, 
-7.7262750109928, -7.7262750109928, -7.7262750109928, -7.7262750109928, 
-7.7262750109928, -7.7262750109928, -7.72654450557804, -7.72654450557804, 
-7.72654450557804, -7.72654450557804, -7.72654450557804, -7.72654450557804, 
-7.72654450557804, -7.72654450557804, -7.72681400016328, -7.72681400016328, 
-7.72681400016328, -7.72681400016328, -7.72681400016328, -7.72681400016328, 
-7.72681400016328, -7.72681400016328, -7.72681400016328, -7.72681400016328, 
-7.72708349474853, -7.72708349474853, -7.72708349474853), uso_car = c("RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", 
"RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp", "RESERVA_LEGAL.shp"
)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Estou criando named vectors para os values e labels quando utilizo o scale-fill_manual:

```
cols<- c(`3` = "black", `4` = "red", `25` = "blue", `67` = "pink", `69` = "green")

labels <- c(`3` = "A", `4` = "B", `25` = "C", `26` = "D")
```

O código fica dessa forma:

```
ggplot() +  
  geom_raster(data=df_dummy, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=CAATINGA))+
  scale_fill_manual("Classes",labels = labels
                    ,values = cols, drop = TRUE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As classes 67 e 68 não possuem nenhum valor no fill do geom_raster que utilizei na coluna CAATINGA e mesmo assim estão aparecendo na legenda. Como faço para retirar estes valores da legenda? Estou utilizando drop = TRUE mas o scale_fill_manual insiste em mostrar os levels sem valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os valores que não estão na coluna `CAATINGA` aparecem na legenda porque estão no vetor `cols`. E como só alguns desses valores também são `names` do vetor `labels`, os que não o são estão na legenda com os `names` que têm em `cols`. Os valores comuns a ambos os vetores estão na legenda com os valores esperados.

Para resolver o problema, no código abaixo usa-se `droplevels` para criar um vetor de níveis presentes na coluna `CAATINGA`. Depois `intersect` para ficar com os valores/nomes comuns aos três vetores, este agora criado, `cols` e `labels`. A seguir o `match` cria índices para extrair só os valores comuns de `cols` e `labels`, a ser usados em `scale_fill_manual`.

Note que há ainda o nível `"21"`, presente em `CAATINGA` mas não no vetor de cores nem no vetor de labels. Esses dados estão a cinzento.

```
library(ggplot2)

cols <- c(`3` = "black", `4` = "red", `25` = "blue", `67` = "pink", `69` = "green")
labels <- c(`3` = "A", `4` = "B", `25` = "C", `26` = "D")

fac <- droplevels(df_dummy$CAATINGA)
common <- intersect(names(cols), names(labels))
common <- intersect(common, levels(fac))
i_cols <- match(common, names(cols))
i_labels <- match(common, names(labels))

ggplot() + 
  geom_raster(data=df_dummy, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=CAATINGA))+
  scale_fill_manual("Classes",labels = labels[i_labels]
                    ,values = cols[i_cols], drop = TRUE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

No entanto, creio que a melhor solução é ter `cols` e `labels` que correspondam aos dados. Os nomes destes dois vetores são os níveis de `CAATINGA`.

```
cols2 <- c(`3` = "black", `4` = "red", `15` = "blue", `21` = "pink", `25` = "green")
labels2 <- c(`3` = "A", `4` = "B", `15` = "C", `21` = "D", `25` = "E")

ggplot() + 
  geom_raster(data=df_dummy, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=CAATINGA))+
  scale_fill_manual("Classes", labels = labels2
                    ,values = cols2
                    ,limits = force    # não chega só drop = TRUE
                    , drop = TRUE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Rui, este df é apenas uma porção de um arquivo raster maior. Eu preciso de vetores nomeados com todas as values e labels existentes pois preciso plotar em facets para cada grupo do raster, onde os levels irá variar. O ggplot já faz esse match entre os vetores nomeados e o valores da variável utilizada para `fill`.  O segredo foi apenas colocar `limits = force` no meu código que já funcionou como esperado. Só não entendi o uso desse argumento. Vc poderia explicar? Obg.

Comment: @Artur_Indio O `force` tem a ver com a *lazy evaluation*. Obriga o R a avaliar os argumentos do `scale_fill_manual` e só depois os passa, já avaliados, à rotina que traça o gráfico. Veja `help("force")`.